# ibdata1, innodb parse corrupted table ibdata1 / Windows, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, innodb

Is it possible to parse corrupted `ibdata1` file throught PHP script? Can you show me how?

I made a `mysqldump` of the `InnoDB` table, but I can get only the first xxxxx rows of data, after these xxxx rows is not possible to get more rows, because these rows are probably corrupted

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 5000,10; //works - returns rows
SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 10000,10; //works - returns rows

SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 10010,10; //fail - mysql error/crash
SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 12000,10; //fail - mysql error/crash
```

I convert `ibdata1` file to utf8 ASCII but there is no structured data for parse - but I can see some usernames,.. so I need to convert `ibdata1` file to some structured ASCII format (to make it able to parse it)

[image: image - ascii ibdata1]

Comment: There are tools to parse InnoDB tablespaces (https://launchpad.net/percona-data-recovery-tool-for-innodb), but they're written in C. Does it really have to be PHP?

Comment: Showing us the actual errors from the crash might be valuable.